# Making decisions in a group: discussing, voting, or else?

Tags: teamwork

I am having regular discussions in a new team of five people. There is no team lead, we all have the same seniority.
When making decisions as a group, we still have to adopt a single method.
As this is a general problem for ALL teams, I would like to understand what has been proven to be the most efficient way of making decisions, balancing effectiveness and inclusiveness:

- discussion among all members, until a single voice comes out and others agree?
- majority vote, with the minority voice(s) who might end up feeling bad, especially if they systematically start from a different POV or culture?
- unanimous vote, discussing and modifying a (majority) solution until everybody finds it acceptable?

In the interest of fairness and participation, I want to use one consistent process, but I just don't know what is normally used. Please advise.

Comment: This a really strange place. I cannot understand why this question is being downvoted. Could anyone share what is the rational behind it? How should OP improve it if nobody is giving any feedback?

Comment: "*but I just don't know what is normally used*" You pick a team lead. I assume you want to exclude that rather obvious answer? Frankly I don't think this is answerable. Handling potential "hurt feelings" is also something you need a team lead for...

Comment: @Lilienthal I specified "there is no team lead" in the question. If the answer was obvious, I would have not created a new question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am asking about a standard procedure, not what the team should decide. I am trying to understand how organisations with teams made of diverse professionals manage to balance efficiency and inclusiveness in situations where everybody has the same seniority.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere are you saying that we can safely close all questions which can be answered with "it depends"? I am very happy to oblige.

Comment: @Monoandale I was hoping to get you to think about *why* you don't have a team lead. Five people can work together if one of them is in charge. Like I said there is no clean way to resolve your situation because the outcome you're hoping for of "we all work together and no one ever is disappointed" simply is not realistic. Your team is setting itself up to fail, spectacularly. Either you get lucky and have a team of professional people working towards a common goal with exceptional professionalism and strong emotional maturity and all goes well. Or dysfunction will seep in eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, a certain culture of discussing is more important in the decision making process than the degree of democracy. Someone always interrupting other speakers or not accepting alternate arguments makes team members feel worse than having the team vote against their proposal based on objective arguments.

So first each team should set common rules for discussions, like

- Don't interrupt anyone.
- Don't dismiss a proposal without hearing arguments for or against it.
- Accept the oppinions and counter-arguments of your team members. Don't feel attacked because someone argues against your solution.
- Document the accepted *and not accepted* proposals (if you realize that the agreed upon solution isn't valid anymore, you don't have to start from scratch).

Then at the beginning of a meeting you should make the goal of the meeting clear to everyone. The goal could be:

- Brainstorming about an idea to find possible solutions.
- Exchanging knowledge about proposed solutions that have been examined in more details than during the brainstorming.
- Comming to a decision and choosing one proposed solution.

The order is important here! You cannot come to a decision if you don't know all the facts yet. So in a typical 1 hour meeting the "exchanging knowledge" phase would take 45 minutes while the "decision making" phase takes only 15 minutes.  <sub>Unfortunately you cannot set these timeframes as rules. Some topics will always be more controversial than others.</sub>

If your team is able to explain, demonstrate and discuss about their ideas in a civilized manner, **they will come to a single voice decision almost naturally.** If they can list (and document) all pro and contra arguments to all solutions, there will be an objective list of facts upon which they can base their vote. Most of the time, the facts will be clear and the vote will be single voiced.

If they cannot agree on one decision, they should continnue discussing, find more pro and contra arguments and rank those based on their importance. Sooner or later, either the "best" solution will be clearly recognizable based on facts, or several solutions are equally valid and it's a matter of personal taste which one is better. In such a case you can let everyone cast their vote and accept the solution with the most votes.

Comment: I find your answer misses the question. What you describe is to how to hold discussion but not which process is the best one.

Comment: I hoped to make it clear that the process of final decision making doesn't matter so much as the process of finding and exchanging all knowledge needed to make a decision. The OP's main concern seems to be "fairness and participation", which I adressed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Elmy I will give this a shot: "If your team is able to explain, demonstrate and discuss about their ideas in a civilized manner, they will come to a single voice decision almost naturally. "

Answer (score 7):

The workplace is not a democracy in any way - at some point there has to be someone who had the authority to say "no, we're doing it this way". That person should always try and establish a consensus, but if they can't, they make the decision and everybody else follows it.

Of course, if the person empowered with the decision making authority frequently makes bad decisions, then they will have *their* authority removed by someone more senior. And so on until you get to the owner(s) of the company - they have ultimate authority because they pay the wages.

Comment: Democracy can only work among similar people, where everyone has the same qualifications (or any at all). This is rarely the case at work so there has to be always someone who makes the final decision.

Comment: @philipkendall thanks, this is a situation where nobody is more senior that others.

Comment: So get whoever is managing you to give somebody authority. You can try some sort of socialist-anarchist collective with no leaders if you *really* want to, but I'd be very surprised if you get a good amount of work done.